# How to express "IFELSE" with R in time series data?

Tags: r

How to use 'if else' to handle the following logic?

```
ifelse(HIGH(yesterday)= CLOSE(yesterday)> OPEN(yesterday)> LOW(yesterday) 
& HIGH (today) = OPEN(today) = CLOSE(today) > LOW(today), 1, 0)
```

give data set `A`

```
A <- data.frame(
    OPEN = c(4.58, 5.00, 5.32, 4.93, 5.72, 6.65,6.80),
    HIGH = c(5.00, 5.00, 5.32,5.57, 6.65, 6.90, 6.80),
    LOW = c(4.58, 5.00, 5.14, 4.93, 5.72, 6.00, 6.80), 
    CLOSE = c(5.00, 5.00,5.29,5.57, 6.65, 6.00, 6.80)).
```

I have already tried

```
ifelse(HIGH(t-1)= CLOSE(t-1)> OPEN(t-1)> LOW(t-1) & HIGH (t) = OPEN(t) =CLOSE(t) > LOW(t), 1, 0)
```

thanks

Comment: Please format your code properly and provide the expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: Also please double-check: Based on your sample data and the conditions, `ifelse` will always return 0. Is that correct? If so, please provide more representative sample data.

Comment: Hi Evers, thanks. it is my part of the dataset. I want to know how to write right code, so return 0 is ok.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: The advice to study R’s syntax is on point. Parentheses areNOT used to index columns of dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note that based on your sample data the `ifelse(...)` statement always returns `0`, so perhaps you should double-check your logic and/or provide better and more presentative sample data.**

**Also note that there is no need for an explicit `ifelse` condition here; it is faster to use the unary operator `+` (or `as.integer`) to convert your logical vector into `1`/`0`.**

In general, this can be done using `dplyr::lag`.

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
    mutate(flag =
        +(lag(HIGH) == lag(CLOSE) &
        lag(CLOSE) > lag(OPEN) &
        lag(OPEN) > lag(LOW) &
        HIGH == OPEN &
        OPEN == CLOSE &
        CLOSE  > LOW))
#  OPEN HIGH  LOW CLOSE flag
#1 4.58 5.00 4.58  5.00    0
#2 5.00 5.00 5.00  5.00    0
#3 5.32 5.32 5.14  5.29    0
#4 4.93 5.57 4.93  5.57    0
#5 5.72 6.65 5.72  6.65    0
#6 6.65 6.90 6.00  6.00    0
#7 6.80 6.80 6.80  6.80    0
```

Comment: Hi Evers, I have a question. if the price is lag2, how to deal with it? ex; HIGH(The day before yesterday)= CLOSE(The day before yesterday), how to write the code? higt(t-2) == close(t-2)?

Comment: @YXCHEN Just use `lag(HIGH, n = 2)` etc.; it's all well explained in `?lag`.

Comment: data.table loses out to dplyr 10:1 on SO ... I think it's time I switch over :)

Comment: @DanY That's surprising. I imagine `data.table` would be faster for larger data sets. I think that's really where the advantage of `data.table`'s reference semantics will kick in.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Agreed!  But I was referring to how the question asker always puts the check on the dplyr solution, not the data.table solution (when both are offered)

Comment: @DanY I like `data.table` (you beat me to a `data.table` option that I was about to add). I think `tidyverse` is just (slightly) more popular overall (definitely with me and in my work).

Answer (score 2):

The issues:

- R doesn't know to look in your dataframe to find `HIGH`.  You have to tell it that `HIGH` is a column of the dataframe `A` by doing this:  `A$HIGH` (there are a few ways to do this using square brackets if you don't like dollar signs).  Similarly for all your other columns.
- Parentheses are not used to index columns of dataframes
- R doesn't know what `t` is.
- Testing of equality with an operator uses `==` instead of `=`.

In addition, you can simplify `ifelse(a>b, 1, 0)` to just `a>b`.

OK, to get to a solution, I like to use `shift` from the `data.table` package for lags/leads and I've named your dataframe `df`:

```
library(data.table)

result <- shift(df$HIGH) == shift(df$CLOSE) &
          shift(df$CLOSE) > shift(df$OPEN) &
          shift(df$OPEN)  > shift(df$LOW) &
          df$HIGH == df$OPEN &
          df$OPEN == df$CLOSE &
          df$CLOSE > df$LOW
```

Notice that with your example data, the result is always false.

I may also suggest that you read a bit on the basic syntax of the language.  [This](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) can be a good place to start.

Comment: @YXCHEN Good luck!